# Updating a field to One-to-many relation field sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I added a field to my existing table and now I have to update the old entries to have the right values.

```
UPDATE shift_job 
SET elapsed_time = ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM actual_end_time - actual_start_time)/60):

ALTER TABLE shift_worker ADD COLUMN actual_work_duration integer NULL;
UPDATE shift_worker
SET actual_work_duration = SUM(SELECT elapsed_time
FROM shift_job 
WHERE shift_worker_id = shift_worker.id);
```

I calculated the elapsed_time for a job and that worked fine. When trying to calculate actual_work_duration for workers I ran into problems. I need to sum all "elapsed_time" fields where shift_worker.id = shift_job.shift_worker_id.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE shift_worker
SET actual_work_duration = (SELECT SUM(elapsed_time)
FROM shift_job 
WHERE shift_worker_id = shift_worker.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the aggregation in a derived table and join to that in the UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE shift_worker
  SET actual_work_duration = t.total_time
FROM (
  select shift_worker_id, SUM(elapsed_time) as total_time
  FROM shift_job 
  group by shift_worker_id
) t
WHERE t.shift_worker_id = shift_worker.id;
```

This is typically much faster than using a co-related subquery.

Comment: . . Do you really find this faster than a correlated subquery, assuming the appropriate indexes are available?  In many databases, the correlated subquery would be faster.  (I'm assuming all or almost all rows would be updated.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, because the aggregation over all rows is faster than running one sub-select for each row in the target table. In my experience the difference is as high as a factor of 4 or 5

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Most databases tend to use sorting algorithms for `group by`, which means they are O(n log n).  That means that breaking up the aggregation into smaller aggregations is typically *faster*.  It is interesting to know that this is not true in Postgres (and in other databases that support and use hash-based aggregation).  I just have to remember that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have seen that to be faster in Oracle as well (using MERGE, instead of an UPDATE with a co-related subquery)